# Localization in Class Librabry project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class library project and two localizations files:

default: SmsApiLocalization.resx
polish: SmsApiLocalization.pl.resx

I'am creating dll file from this project and using this file in WinForms application. Problem is, WinForms application is taking values only from SmsApiLocalization.pl.resx (I'am guessing because I have Windows 10 in polish version), no matter what language I'am setting in Program.cs. When I set something like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
```

Winforms app always takes values from SmsApiLocalization.pl.resx and ignore other localizations. Do Yow how to fix this? I want to create multilanguage Dll file and use this in differents projects.

Comment: Is library project a part of solution used to create winforms application? You more likely have problem with satelites, can you show solution tree and `bin` folder of where exe-file is? I assume language selection is working properly for winforms app, otherwise show how do you switch language and all relevant code.

Comment: No, this Class Library is not a part of solution, it is alone project. We are going to use this dll in differents projects with already working localizations.